# ncr Combinations with pyspark nc3

Tags: pyspark

```
random42 = sorted(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y'])
```

Need a ncr output to have the below three label combination in pyspark code

['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE', 'AAF', 'AAG', 'AAH', 'AAI', 'AAJ', 'AAK', 'AAL', 'AAM', 'AAN', 'AAO', 'AAP', 'AAQ', 'AAR', 'AAS','BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAD', 'BAE', 'BAF', 'BAG', 'BAH', 'BAI', 'BAJ','BAK', 'BAL', 'BAM', 'BAN', 'BAO', 'BAP', 'BAQ', 'BAR', 'BAS', 'BAT', 'BAU', 'BAV'...'YYT', 'YYU', 'YYV', 'YYW', 'YYX', 'YYY']

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2])
>>> sorted(rdd.cartesian(rdd).collect())
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I need a three letter combination like

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> sorted(rdd.cartesian(rdd).collect())
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 4), (2,3,5)]
```

I am looking out in pyspark, since I have more than 1000 as my elements to choose
1000 C_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example implemented with a spark data frame that will help you. The main idea is to use `itertools.combinations` and `udf`.

Note: You can convert from your RDD to a spark data frame to adapt to my example.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

#create a sample data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['A','B','C','D','E'],),(['F','G','H','I','J'],)],('txt',))
df.show()

# +---------------+
# |            txt|
# +---------------+
# |[A, B, C, D, E]|
# |[F, G, H, I, J]|
# +---------------+

#udf part
def ncr(x,r):
    return [''.join(_) for _ in itertools.combinations(x, r)]

r = 3

udf_ncr = F.udf(lambda t: ncr(t,r), ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn('output', udf_ncr('txt'))

df.show(truncate=False)

# +---------------+--------------------------------------------------+
# |txt            |output                                            |
# +---------------+--------------------------------------------------+
# |[A, B, C, D, E]|[ABC, ABD, ABE, ACD, ACE, ADE, BCD, BCE, BDE, CDE]|
# |[F, G, H, I, J]|[FGH, FGI, FGJ, FHI, FHJ, FIJ, GHI, GHJ, GIJ, HIJ]|
# +---------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Edit: added an implementation example with rdd as follows,

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(['A','B','C','D','E']),(['F','G','H','I','J'])])

def ncr(x,r):
    return [''.join(_) for _ in itertools.combinations(x, r)]

r = 3

rdd.map(lambda x: ncr(x,r)).collect()

#[['ABC', 'ABD', 'ABE', 'ACD', 'ACE', 'ADE', 'BCD', 'BCE', 'BDE', 'CDE'],
# ['FGH', 'FGI', 'FGJ', 'FHI', 'FHJ', 'FIJ', 'GHI', 'GHJ', 'GIJ', 'HIJ']]
```